# Measuring area with n amount of gps coordinates

Tags: javascript, dictionary, gps, coordinates

I need to be able to measure area with n amount amount of gps coordinates using javascript / jquery. I was not able to find this done using javascript or with n amount of coordinates so I decided to ask if anyone knows how to?

One example would be that I have 6 seperate lat / lon coordinates which I need to use to measure their area in square meters.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will only work for convex polygons formed from latitude/longitude points.  The majority of the work is in rearranging the latitude/longitude points in counter-clockwise order.  Once the reordering is done, you can find the area of the irregular polygon easily.

```
//make sure to add the first term to the end of both arrays

//              ---------------SAME---------------
//             |                                  |
var lats = [25.767368, 34.088808, 40.727093, 25.767368];
//             |                                  |
var lons = [-80.18930, -118.40612, -73.97864, -80.18930];

//get the average center point of the polygon
var lats_sum = 0;
var lons_sum = 0; 

for (var i=lats.length; i--;) {
    lats_sum += lats[i];
    lons_sum += lons[i]; 
}

var lat_origin = lats_sum / lats.length; 
var lon_origin = lons_sum / lons.length; 

//translate origin to (0,0) by shifting lat lons
//and calculate the standard angle of the point
var angles = new Array(lats.length); 

for (var j=lats.length; j--;) {
    lats[j] -= lat_origin; 
    lons[j] -= lon_origin; 

    if (lons[j] >= 0 && lats[j] >= 0) {
        angles[j] = Math.abs(Math.atan(lats[j]/lons[j]) * 180 / Math.PI); 
    } else if (lons[j] < 0 && lats[j] >= 0) {
        angles[j] = 90 + Math.abs(Math.atan(lats[j]/lons[j]) * 180 / Math.PI); 
    } else if (lons[j] < 0 && lats[j] < 0) {
        angles[j] = 180 + Math.abs(Math.atan(lats[j]/lons[j]) * 180 / Math.PI); 
    } else if (lons[j] >= 0 && lats[j] < 0) {
        angles[j] = 270 + Math.abs(Math.atan(lats[j]/lons[j]) * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
}

//re-arrange the points from least to greatest angle 
var cur_ang, cur_lat, cur_lon; 

for (var l = 0; l < angles.length; l++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < angles.length - 1; k++) {
        cur_ang = angles[k]; 
        cur_lat = lats[k]; 
        cur_lon = lons[k]; 

        if (cur_ang < angles[k+1]) {
            angles[k] = angles[k+1];
            lats[k] = lats[k+1]; 
            lons[k] = lons[k+1]; 

            angles[k+1] = cur_ang; 
            lats[k+1] = cur_lat; 
            lons[k+1] = cur_lon; 
        }
    }
}

//calculate area for irregular polygon
var sum1 = 0;
var sum2 = 0; 

for (var t = 0; t < lats.length; t++) {

    if (t != lats.length - 1) {

        sum1 += lats[t] * lons[t+1];
        sum2 += lons[t] * lats[t+1]; 

    } else {

        sum1 += lats[t] * lons[0]; 
        sum2 += lons[t] * lats[0]; 

    }
}

var area = (sum1 - sum2) / 2.0;

console.log("Area: " + area);
```

Then when it comes to converting that lat lon area to meters squared I have no idea.  This is a function I found online that may help you get a start.

```
// Use to convert from lat long dist to meters
function measure(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2){  // generally used geo measurement function
    var R = 6378.137; // Radius of earth in KM
    var dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180;
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c;
    return d * 1000; // meters
}
```

Comment: Thanks! If the area measurement above works it is huge help already. Going to test it tomorrow and trying to find something for the square meters / kilometers convertion.

Comment: It seems if I use real coordinates and small distance changes (as it would be) like                                                      var lats = [51.5072, 51.5172, 51.5272, 51.5372, 51.5472]; 
var lons = [0.1275, 0.1175, 0.1075, 0.0975, 0.0875];                                 Sum1 and Sum2 end up being the same and total area is 0

Comment: Well given that those points create a straight line, the area would end up being basically zero. Also, make sure that the length of both arrays are the same. You have 1 too many in your lons array.

Comment: It seems I added the extra for this comment, sorry. But did not think about the straight line either. I used 4 gps points from the map that I know form a square which square kilometers I know and I got the answer: -6.426489562727511e-9. This is correctly what I should be having at this point for to convert to square meters / miles / kilometers?

Comment: No, I forgot that the order that the lat lons are placed in the array matters.  You must go through them in a counter-clockwise order, or you will not get the correct results. I'll look into changing that and update the code when I figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble :) I am trying to figure this out also but never used this kind of math yet. Your code is also so simple and short compared to any other there is which is very good.